# CustomBinding lacks a TransportBindingElement when trying to add GZip compression to WCF

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, web-config

I am trying to add GZip to the binding of my WCF service and i get the next error

```
The Scheme cannot be computed for this binding because this CustomBinding lacks a TransportBindingElement.  Every binding must have at least one binding element that derives from TransportBindingElement.
```

my web config contains the following:

```
 <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="BinaryCompressionBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat ="GZip"/>
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:10:00" transferMode="StreamedResponse" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior" name="SMS.Example.Service">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="customBinding" binding="customBinding" name="customBinding" contract="SMS.Example.IService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
```

what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your endpoint node. The binding configuration attribute is missing. Add bindingConfiguration="BinaryCompressionBinding" and try again.